# Gradle. Удаление файлов в режиме --parallel

Tags: java, gradle

Есть проект с темами на npm. При сборке в каждой папке темы создаётся папка node_modules, которая задачей clean не удаляется. Сейчас я удаляю так:

```
clean {
    doLast {
        subprojects.each {
            if (it.path.contains("themes")) {
                def node_modulesPath = "$projectDir" + it.path.replace(':', File.separator) + File.separator + "node_modules"

                file(node_modulesPath).deleteDir()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но всё происходит в одном потоке, даже если добавить ключ --parallel. Как написать свою универсальную задачу для удаления папок в разных подпроектах, чтобы в параллельном режиме они удалялись параллельно?

Comment: Не вижу сходства: чтение одного файла и удаление директорий из разных подпроектов.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, есть задача cleanNPM, которая решает все мои проблемы. Надо внимательней смотреть имеющиеся задачи (gradle tasks).